# springboot dockerfile dockercompose postgres error "localhost:5432 refused"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have problem with my dockerfile and my docker-compose connect to my postgres (container). this is my error
 `Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.`

this my properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres-db:5432/offer
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
logging.level.org.hibernate.sql=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
springdoc.api-docs.path=/api-docs

#server.port=8085

spring.devtools.restart.log-condition-evaluation-delta=false
```

my Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
EXPOSE 8085
VOLUME /tmp
ADD target/weShareJob-service-offer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar offer.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-Dspring.profiles.active=container", "-jar", "offer.jar"]
```

docker-compose

```
version: "3"
services:
  postgres-db:
    image: postgres:latest
    network_mode: bridge
    container_name: postgres-db
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    expose:
      - 5432
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=offer
    restart: unless-stopped
  # APP*****************************************
  offer:
    image: offer:latest
    network_mode: bridge
    container_name: offer
    expose:
      - 8085
    ports:
      - 8085:8085
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - postgres-db
    links:
      - postgres-db
volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

i don't uderstand why my error say i try connect "localhost:5432" or i passed postgres-db in my url. i have check other answer of question similair of me.

thanks for help :)

Comment: I once had a problem when my container name contained the `-` special char, although formally it's valid...

Comment: hi wasilewski thansk for answer. i have try without  '-'. my error rest the same Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

Comment: Try to connect to `localhost` instead...

Comment: You use `container` profile (`-Dspring.profiles.active=container`) in `ENTRYPOINT` when you create the container.  Can you please provide the content for this profile? Maybe you have application-container.properties in your project? Because I have tried your configurations and they work.

Comment: hi Aleh Birulia  i have change "contanier" by "dev" or "application" the name of properties file but the resutl is the same. i didn't have container.properties but application.properties. this the result in terminal for Spring profile `The following profiles are active: dev`. when i build the image for project ` ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-Dspring.profiles.active=dev", "-jar", "offer.jar"]
 ---> Running in 4313763d796c
Removing intermediate container 4313763d796c
 ---> 4e58123c3871
Successfully built 4e58123c3871
Successfully tagged offer:latest`.

Comment: this link of my project `https://gitlab.com/MisterThomas/wesharejoblocal/-/tree/master/weShareJob-service-offer`

Answer (score -1):

i see you are starting your application with

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=container
```

so i wonder how your application properties looks for the profile container?

are you sure the container profile gets started (did you check in the output?)